# number of ways in which N can be represented as product of K factors in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, algorithm, sorting

give a number N, a array of all its factors, a number K... we need to find number of ways in which N can be represented as product of K factors, i.e.
if

```
N=64
K=3
arr = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
```

so number of ways would be 7 because

```
1x1x64=64
1x2x32=64
1x4x16=64
1x8x8=64
```

and so on

Comment: There is a lot of similar questions in the last days. The same instructor or online contest?

Comment: since your are given N, then the array of its factors is redundant; you can deduce it. Second aspect - the tag node.js is really irrelevant - javascript is enough to specify the language of implementation

Answer (score 1):

To get combinations with a length of `k` from the array we could use a recursive generator:

```
function* combinations(array, k, i = 0, prepend = []) {
  if(!k) {
    yield prepend;
  } else {
    while(i < array.length)
      yield* combinations(array, k - 1, i /*+ 1*/, prepend.concat(array[i++]));
 }
}
```

*(The commented out +1 is to exclude duplicates (`1 * 1 * 1`), but that behaviour seems to be not wanted by the OP)*

So to get all combinations we could do:

```
[...combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)] // [1, 2], [1, 3] ...
```

Now we just have to multiply them up:

```
const multiply = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
```

And filter out those that are N:

```
[...combinations(arr, K)].filter(el => multiply(el) === N).length
```

which will return `7`.

*PS: Yes there are easier and faster approaches, but I sometimes just want to use some rare (but cool) language features :)*

Answer (score 0):

This will create a 2D array with all non-repeating combinations.

```
  var n = 64
  var factors = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
  var rep = []

  for (var f1 = 0; f1 < factors.length; f1++) {
    for (var f2 = 0; f2 < factors.length; f2++) {
      for (var f3 = 0; f3 < factors.length; f3++) {
        if (factors[f1]*factors[f2]*factors[f3] == n && factors[f3] >= factors[f2] && factors[f2] >= factors[f1]) {
          rep.push([factors[f1], factors[f2], factors[f3]])
        }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(rep.length) // Get the amount of combinations
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the decomposition of N as prime factors. It looks like:
[image]

where a1, a2, .. ax are the prime factors of N. We can further expand this formula as:
[image]

In order to produce the K factors required by the problem, we will have to pick from the prime numbers listed above.Any of the prime numbers can be picked, in any order, so basically in this formula I can replace the prime numbers with an abstract symbol.

[image]

How many ways are there to split N as a product of K numbers? Just as many ways to group these underscores into K groups - one group for each of the K numbers. For the first underscore, there are K possibilities of assigning it to a group; similarly, there are K possibilities for each of the underscore. In total, the number of possibilities is 
[image]

[this is basically a partitioning problem: we split b1+b2+..+bx items into K sets]

Now the only remaining problem is to determine the decomposition of N into prime factors. Or, even better, determine directly the sum b1+b2+...+bx.

```
counter=0;
for(int i=2;i<square_root(N);i++)
    if(N%i==0) //i is a divisor of N
       {
           int M=N;
           while(M%i==0)
               {
                   counter++;
                   M=M/i;
               }
       }
```